# Chebychev's formula with upper bound

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ & $Y$ are independent with respective variances $9$ & $16$. $E(X)=E(Y)$

Use Chebychev's inequality to put an upper bound on $P(|X-Y|\ge 10)$

I have been looking around online trying to figure out how to go about this problem and haven't been very successful. I have found a lot about a lower bound but almost nothing on upper bounds. I don't know how I ended up doing what I did but so far I have

$10 < X < 28$ and $10 < Y < 42$

$\sigma = 3 $  for $x$

$\sigma = 4 $  for $y$

$median(X)=19$

$median(Y)=26$

Comment: The lower bound is $0$, e.g. if $X=\pm 3$ and independently $Y=\pm 4$ each equiprobably

Answer (score 1):

Let $W=X-Y$. Then $E(W)=0$, and because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the variance of $W$, that is, the variance of $X-Y$, is $9+16$.

Now recall the Chebyshev Inequality: If the random variable $T$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then
$$\Pr(|T-\mu|\ge \sigma k) \le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Note that this gives an **upper bound**, namely $\dfrac{1}{k^2}$, for $\Pr(|T-\mu|\ge \sigma k)$.

This will probably enough for you to solve the problem.